# Shortcut to move cursor to input text in Find Navigator-Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the shortcut to move cursor to input textfield in Find Navigator in Xcode?

For example, there is a image and I want to find where the image is used in Xcode project. I copy the image's name in Project Navigator (Cmd+C), then move to the Find Navigator (Cmd+3). I want to know shortcut to move cursor to input text field instead click mouse to the text field.

Does anyone know what the shortcut is? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you press CMD+3, try SHIFT+TAB once or press TAB three times. Let me know if it works

Comment: Glad I could help. Thanks!